# Share links button for all apps in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I have the next share ImageView button in my android project:

```
final ImageView share = findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plane");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, some_url_from_my_app);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Using"));
            }
        });
```

My problem is when i click on the button i am seeing only few apps and not all the apps in my phone as i want, like Facebook, Instagarm etc...

What should i do in order to see all the apps in my phone in order to be able to share the link to all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and few hours I managed to solve the issue.
What I have done is instead of doing:

```
myIntent.setType("text/plane");
```

I made it like:

```
myIntent.setType("text/*");
```

That's showed me all the apps for sharing.
And about the Facebook share I used the Facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Take the startActivity line out.

Create a XML Resource folder with the name menu inside the res folder.
Create a layout menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/share_menu">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

Make sure you override the onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
...
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    // R.<XML resource folder>.<XML layout filename>
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this share button is for menu item and not for a regular button which is my case… I have a button just in the middle.of the page and when I click it I share some link, the share action is working for me but not showing all installed apps that I have in the phone.

Comment: @Danny is there a way that you could share a screenshot; as well as, exposed more information about your code?